# Can we pass a Func<T,TResult> to a middleware in .Net core 5 to execute?

Tags: c#, .net, exception, .net-core, asp.net-core-middleware

So, I am trying to create a middleware which converts the Exception to a specific Error.

Now there a two project that wants to implement the Same Middleware but have there own logic to Handling error messages.

I want to abstract the way you handle Exception to each project and work done by this middle ware will just to convert the ErrorResponse to a json and send back to user.

The Middleware code is

```
public class ExceptionHandlingMiddleware
{
    public RequestDelegate requestDelegate;
    private readonly Func<Exception, ErrorResponse> _errorResponse;

    public ExceptionHandlingMiddleware(RequestDelegate requestDelegate, Func<Exception, ErrorResponse> errorResponse)
    {
        this.requestDelegate = requestDelegate;
         _errorResponse = errorResponse;
    }
    public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
    {
        try
        {
            await requestDelegate(context);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            var error = _errorResponse(ex);
            await HandleException(context, error);
        }
    }
    private static Task HandleException(HttpContext context, ErrorResponse error)
    {
        var errorMessage = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(error);

        context.Response.ContentType = "application/json";
        context.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError;

        return context.Response.WriteAsync(errorMessage);
    }
}
```

I created an Extension method

```
        public static IApplicationBuilder UseExceptionHandling(this IApplicationBuilder app, Func<Exception, ErrorResponse> errorResponse)
    {
        return app.UseMiddleware<ExceptionHandlingMiddleware>(errorResponse);
    }
```

Now I am using it like this , but this gives me an object reference not set to an instance of an object

```
  app.UseExceptionHandling(HandleException);

    private static ErrorResponse HandleException(Exception ex)
    {
        return new ErrorResponse() { Code = "Foo" };
    }
```

and _errorResponse (in middleware) seems to be null.

Let me know if this is the wrong way to do.

Comment: Are you getting any `NullReferenceException`? If `_errorResponse` is null then the line `var error = _errorResponse(ex)` should throw an exception.

Comment: Yes, ```var error = _errorResponse(ex);``` throws a `NullReferenceException`. Any idea how can I solve this ? Why is the _errorResponse null  if this is being passed  when told to use the Middleware ```app.UseExceptionHandling(HandleException);```

Comment: have you tried to debug the code? Try setting a breakpoint in the `UseExceptionHandling` method and find out if `errorResponse` is null there as well.

Comment: The code looks right. When you put a break point in the constructor of the middleware, does it have a null value passed into it for errorResponse?

Answer (score -1):

*I think the middleware that you want to catch exceptions and customize error messages is wrong.*

**Reason:**

Suppose there is an Exception in the controller, although you pass it to `ExceptionHandlingMiddleware`, but when you execute the `public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)` method, you can be sure that the `catch (Exception ex)` is what you passed in Is Exception the same?

***So you don't need to struggle how to pass a Func<T,TResult> to a middleware.***

#### Suggestion:

Below article should be useful to you.

[ASP.NET Core 3.1 - Global Error Handler Tutorial](https://jasonwatmore.com/post/2020/10/02/aspnet-core-31-global-error-handler-tutorial)

Comment: First of all I want to thank you for the answer , But if you see the handling of exception part , there is a `switch` statement. And the with this is if any new exception is added to the Application this needs to be handled here and now the developer can write any object in the response. I want to abstract this to a method which only return a Standar error response and then use this in multiple project .